# react is it a good idea to pass functions to child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a parent and child component.

In the child component, input field gets changed and I want to let parent know about this change.  So the way i am doing it now is this.

```
//parent component
const [text, setText] = useState<any>('');

<childComponent :text={text} :setText={setText} />

//child component
export const childComponent: React.FC<childComponent> = ({
  text,
  setText
}) => {

   return (
     <input :value={text} onChange={(value) => setText(value)} />
   )

}
```

Is this the right way of doing it ? maybe I should be passing the ordinary function from parent to child, and in that function in the parent, I should be calling `setText`. Not sure really.

I come from `vue.js` world where I really liked the whole concept of `$emit`. In the child, you could write this:

```
<input onChange={(val) => { $emit('updateInput', val) } />

// and in the parent

<childComponent @updateInput={(val) => parentValue = val}
```

Basically, most of the time, you wouldn't need to pass functions from parent to child and I really loved that.

I'd appreciate an experienced answer of how you handle this in React.

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly acceptable. This is done all the time. For example, UI frameworks like antd and material-ui all have their own button implementations, which all accept event listeners. They are not true event listeners, in a sense. They are passed downwards to the actual HTML button. The name of the prop just so happens to be called `onClick`

Comment: That’s fine. It can get confusing if you start drilling props and in that case you can use Context or Redux to avoid it.

Comment: For some reason, I better love `Vue.js's $emit` capability. Don't you agree ?

Comment: Like they said, it's a really common pattern. At work we are working on our custom UI Library and we do this all the time for handlers.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili I don't see how React's implementation is any different. You are calling a named function in a child (it is named during the downward passing, `updateInput`) that was defined in the parent. You can do the exact same thing in react. It doesn't have to be named in the parent. It can be passed in as an anonymous function and then invoked as a named one. Exact same thing, different syntax

Comment: the difference is I don't pass `updateInput` or anything like this from parent to child. in react, I still have to pass the function.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili This is simply not true. You end up calling a function on your `input`. In `$emit`, you are passing the string value. In react, you are calling the property name. In both situations, you need to call it based on explicit information that is derived from the parent. Also, Vue is JavaScript. There's no magic that Vue can do that somehow does _not_ append an event listener to that `input` element. In both situations, you need to have knowledge (the name) from the parent and it does the exact same thing under the hood. Again, same operation, different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly acceptable. It is even described explicitly in the official React Documents in the section about [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

Answer (score 2):

That is perfectly fine and it's a common way for a children to communicate with its parent.

There is however something to consider. When you write a callback directly in a JSX template it is reevaluated on every render cycle which means that a new function is created every time.

There are two React hooks to help mitigate this (which could lead to performance issues) [`useCallback`](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and [`useMemo`](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). They both help memoize functions in order to send them again in further render cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am writing my thoughts .

First , when child Input field will change it will trigger an update state function .

Now look what will happen .

The parent will re-render with all of its nested child.

It may cause on huge performance issue .
If u don't care about performance then its fine .

else .

Give a `ref` to parent and access the required child and it's value when u need without retendering the components .

Redd about these hooks and do what ever suited for your problem .

useRef() . uesEffect()